# Swipe does not work with UITableview's scrollview and Pull to Refresh in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have created `UITableView` with Scrollview and given swipe gesture to swipe from left to right and vice-versa between three different views. Both of them don't seem to work with each other. On top of this I have a pull to refresh functionality on the `UITableView`. I have tried to implement `UIGestureRecogniser` delegate method but it doesn't seem to work.Any Suggestions?

I have realised that when the bouncing is disabled on the scrollview the swipe functionality works fine, but Pull-to-refresh does not work in this case.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a UITableView inside a UIScrollView? You don't need to do that, because a table view already supports scrolling.

Comment: No. UITableView with Default scrolling action, but When we scrolls TableView content and bouncing is enabled that time swipe action is not working properly